# Using if statements on multiple instance variables in one view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a rails app where a user model has several has_many relationships with other models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :model_2s
    has_many :model_3s
    has_many :model_4s

end
```

I am then creating a profile page where I display data from each of these models for the current user. I am doing this using a separate controller - profiles_controller.rb

In the profiles controller I am creating instance variables for each of these models based on the current user:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @model_2s = @user.model_2s.all
    @model_3s = @user.model_3s.all
    @model_4s = @user.model_4s.all
end
```

I am then able to display data from these instance variables in the show view for profiles. I do this by calling an each method.

The functionality I am now trying to add is to show some default data (like Lorem Ipsum placeholder text) for fields that the user has not filled in.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to check if a particular field in these instance variables is empty.

For example, I would like something along the lines of:

```
<% if @model_2s.field_1.empty? %>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<% else %>
    <%= @model_2s.field_1 %>
<% end %>
```

However this gives an "undefined method 'field_1'... " error.

I know how to check for @model_2s.any? to confirm the instance variable itself is present, but I want to be able to do a conditional check at the next level down - the fields within the instance variable.

Comment: `@model_2s` is an enumerable (array). You can test it's empty with `@model_2s.empty?` or you can test a particular element with `@model_2s.first.field_1.blank?` (here the first element is checked)

Comment: thanks... unfortunately after adding '.first' I still get the same error... "undefined method 'field_1'... "

Comment: Then your `@model_2s` array is empty. You will first have to check whether anything is found at all, probably by doing something like `if @model_2s.empty? || @model_2s.first.field_1.blank?`.

Comment: use this "@model_2s.respond_to?('field_1')"

Comment: @JaapHaagmans - model_2s is not empty, I am able to loop over it and pull out other fields. I think the issue as per the answers below is that I was trying to do the if outside of an each loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if `@model_2s.first.field_1` returns an `undefined method` error, @model_2s is empty or the field_1 attribute doesn't exist. Looping through it will indeed solve the error, but only if the `@model_2s` array was empty to begin with.

Comment: apologies, this must be my mistake @JaapHaagmans, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing in your view, but definitely you need to loop each of those result sets if you want to access something like `field_1`

```
<% @model_2s.each do |m| %>

    <% if m.field_1.empty? %>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <% else %>
        <%= m.field_1 %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This also handles the case when `@model_2s` is empty.

Comment: Great, thanks. Couple of questions - 1. Is there an easy explanation as to why you can only access the fields of an instance variable by using an each loop? and 2. If I need to do this over a number of models in my view, should I be setting them up as helper methods?

Comment: 1) because you're working with an array (actually an ActiveRecord::Relation which behaves as an Array), and the way you deal with arrays is usually by looping :). 2) yes, of course, you can use helper methods to clean up the view code

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<% if @model_2s %>
 <% @model_2s.each do |model_2| %>
  <% if model_2.field_1.empty? %>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <% else %>
      <%= model_2.field_1 %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It will be inside the loop..

Comment: you can not call field_1 on an enumerable. may be you can loop through @model_2s to get the object, the method/attribute (field_1) is defined for.

Comment: thanks @Thahakp - seems the same point as the other answer - I needed to be looping through the instance variable.